# How to get external Extension in static blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I downloaded and using a Testimonial extension now I need to get content of that extension into a static block so that I display my testimonials in pages.I use magebuzz testimonial  extension and I contacted the developer support as it is a free extension they said they will not provide any code support.

Comment: The extension should come with an xml file in the layout folder of your theme. There are some blocks defined there. If you don't have experience with Magento layouts, post it's content in your question, please.

Comment: yes I know every extension has .xml files and this extenion too had now my requirement is how to get content of this extension to be inserted in a static block.for example if some testimonials are created I want those testimonials to be in my static block so that I can display them in my homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-->As you said you are using magebuzz testimonial section you will have `testimonial.phtml` here `app/design/frontend/blissblossoms/default/template/testimonial` duplicate `testimonial.phtml` lets save it as `testimonial1.phtml`

-->Now lets create a static block lets name it as `testimonials` and id is `home_testimonials` add the following code into the `content` of that `static block`

```
`{{block type="testimonial/testimonial" name="testimonial1"template="testimonial/testimonial1.phtml"}}`
```

now finally call this static block in `page.xml/local.xml` file in this way

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml"> 
       <block type="cms/block" name="testimonials">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_testimonials</block_id></action>
       </block>
</block>
```

This should display testimonials in your footer.